Current state of science on doxastic voluntarism?
Doxastic Voluntarism is the hypothesis that one can, in some degree, choose what one believes.  Traditionally, this has been debated by philosophers, but there has been some scientific research into the matter.
Is there a current scientific consensus on whether or not people can control their own beliefs?  What is the best evidence currently either for or against this hypothesis?
